# reverse of the string using recursion

Tags: c++

Hey guys i get stuck in the unusual situation. This is my code, it works perfectly for returning the reverse of the string but it gives output with including the space so I don't want that space to be included in my programme output so anyone has suggestions about this plz share it... by the way this is my code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string reverse(string str, int size) {
  if (size == -1)
    return "";
  else
    {
      char a;
      a = str[size];
      return a + reverse(str, size - 1);
    }
}

int main() {
  int size;
  cout << "the size of the string : ";
  cin >> size;
  string str;
  cout << "enter the word : ";
  cin >> str;
  cout << reverse(str, size);
}
```

Comment: I think you should take a minute to learn [how to format posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)...

Comment: Can you clarify which space you are referring to? Might be best to give sample input and the corresponding sample output. Also, I would suggest that you surround the output with single quotes so you can actually tell where the string starts and ends.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `std::string`, you don't need to specify the size of the string, but use the `std::string::size()` or `std::string::length()` member functions. Also, `a = str[size];` is problematic when `size` equals to the size of the string, since you perform an out of bound access (remember that C++ uses zero-based indexing). You can simplify the code a lot, ending up with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t

using namespace std;

string reverse(string str, std::size_t pos) {
    return (pos == 0 ? "" : str[pos - 1] + reverse(str, pos - 1));
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cout << "enter the word : ";
    getline(cin, str); // allow for spaces in the string
    cout << reverse(str, str.size()) << endl;
}
```

Here, instead of using `cin >> str`, I used `getline(cin, str)`, since `cin` reads up to the first whitespace, whereas `getline` allows to read `string`s that containg spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Change the implementation of the function `reverse` to the following.

```
string reverse(string str ,int size){
    if (size==-1)
        return "";
    else
    {
        char a;
        a=str[size];
        if (' ' == a )
            return reverse(str,size-1)
        else
            return a+reverse(str,size-1);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, do some pre-processing on th input.

Comment: e.g if i give input : "mohsin" 
output should be "nishom" and well that is fine it gives the same output but it includes the space before the output mohsin .............

Comment: @MohsinMushtaq Also, this is C++. The `string` class has a `length` value you can use without having to pass the size.